# How can I make my camera only go up, when there is higher elevation?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, camera

I am trying to develop a 2D plattformer game. I already made a code for the camera so it follows my player. It works perfectly fine but i have one problem. How do i make it so it doesn't follow my jump? I only want the y.axis camera to only go higher when the elevation of the ground goes higher as well. How do I make it work? I wasn't able to find anything about it. I don't want the camera to follow my player when jumping, but only if the elevation of the ground is higher.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraFollow : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;
    public float smoothing = 5.0f;
    public float yOffset = 0.0f;

    private Vector3 offset;

    private void Start()
    {
        offset = transform.position - target.position;
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 targetCamPos = target.position + offset;
        targetCamPos.y += yOffset;

        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, targetCamPos, smoothing * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can cast a ray from the player position downwards and detect the ground. If the ground is higher than the camera position, you can adjust the camera position.